# Bad Low-Quality Audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Despite having received (before I saw it) 5 unanimous upvotes, I think this ought to be closed (off-topic / lacks sufficient information to diagnose). It has no code and is basically just asking for a debugging tutorial.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4783967

Comment: So go and vote accordingly and it will disappear as an audit.

Comment: I concurr and did so. BTW: It's 23 days old and never updated nor answered.

Answer (score 4):

It is amazing sometimes what gets up voted. I expect most users don't realize what effect their up votes have once they get access to the review queues.

The question that was used in that audit in now correctly *processed* as can be seen in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VI6pG.png).

If you run into an audit that you feel is incorrect and wonder if you should change the way you review you can post on meta to get the audit of the queue by taking the correct action by visiting the question. If you want to consult some regular reviewers first, feel free to drop in message in the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room where the members are happy to help out.

Comment: Just look at the vote timestamps on days the user got more than one vote.  Not so amazing.  This kind of hanky-panky gets to be less than innocent when it causes reviewers to fail an audit.