# What is the reasoning behind this close review audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I just voted to close a question (see below), but it was an audit and shouldn't have been closed, according to said audit.

My reasoning was that it is at least a really broad question ('when would I want to use'), mixed with some opinion based problems ('some trade-offs and design concerns'). 
Combine those two with a link to another thread but no explanation of what the information there lacked according to the OP (or what it did help), I figured this was not going places. Hence my vote.

Was I wrong? The audit seems to think so, so I assume the answer is yes, but to really learn from this, can someone put more specifics on the wrongness of my reasoning?

I have not tagged this 'disputed', as until proven otherwise I assume there is some fault with my reasoning which I must correct. I/we/someone can add this later if there is no satisfying answer, as I believe audits must not be controversial if they are to be helpfull :)

> **Difference between @Delegate, @Mixin and Traits in Groovy?**
>
> Would someone explain when I would want to use Groovy Traits
>   vs. Mixins (@Mixin) vs. Delegates (@Delegate)? Maybe some trade-offs
>   and design concerns would help.
>
> They all seem to allow for reusing multiple "classes" of behavior.
>   Thanks. :-)
>
> This SO thread was helpful too: *Difference between @Delegate and
>   @Mixin AST transformations in Groovy*

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4818973) is the audit in question.

Comment: It seems that close review audit questions are just automatically-selected questions that have all upvotes and no downvotes. Occasionally a borderline question has no downvotes and gets selected as an audit. (I'm assuming the downvotes have occurred since you posted here). Happened to me recently too http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254399/bad-low-quality-audit